# Le estamos atendiendo

Tags: selección-de-palabras, laísmo-leísmo-loísmo

He oído muchas veces en las grabaciones que ponen al tenerte en espera en una llamada telefónica como a un Call Center que dicen "Por favor espere, **le** estamos atendiendo", creo que está equivocado (leísmo) y debería ser "lo estamos atendiendo".

¿Es correcto "le estamos atendiendo"?

Según yo, por lo siguiente "**lo**" es correcto.

> **Lo** estamos atendiendo (a él).
>
> La estamos atendiendo (a ella).
>
> **Lo** estamos atendiendo (a usted).

Comment: A mí personalmente me suena mejor _le_, pero quizá es porque soy madrileño, y por tanto _leista_. Lo que me parece incorrecto es que te digan que te estan atendiendo precisamente cuando **no** te estan atendiendo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como leí en la WikiLengua creo que entra dentro del leismo de cortesia. Copio un fragmento.

> También está aceptado el llamado «leísmo de cortesía», esto es, la utilización de le/les en sustitución de lo/la y los/las cuando se refiere a usted/ustedes.

```
  ¿Quiere que le lleve hasta el restaurante? [«Leísmo de cortesía»] 
  ¿Quiere que LO/LA lleve hasta el restaurante? [Uso CORRECTO]
```

> He aquí algunos usos correctos (de uso frecuente en Hispanoamérica) que suelen sustituirse en España por el «leísmo de cortesía»:

```
 Nuestra compañía LO/LA informa de que tiene un mensaje nuevo. [También es correcta la construcción le informa que...] 
¿En qué puedo ayudarLO?  
 LO atendió la señora Lucía Rodríguez. [En los billetes de compra] 
 Encantado de conocerLO. 
 Sin más, LOS saludamos atentamente... [En las cartas formales] 
 LO/LA felicito por el premio que ha obtenido. 
 LO/LA invitamos a nuestra fiesta, que tendrá lugar el día... 
 Señor Aguirre y señora Gómez, LOS obligamos a comparecer ante el tribunal. 
 Muchas gracias por entregar su currículo; ya LO/LA llamaremos.
```

[Referencia: WikiLengua](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Le%C3%ADsmo)

Así se puede usar le/lo para sexo masculino, le/la para el femenino.

Respecto al comentario de "Le ayudo" me es común oír el uso de "Le" en vez de “Lo” (vivo en el norte de España). Segun la [RAE](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/?key=le%C3%ADsmo&origen=REDPD)

> Otro grupo que ofrece confusión es el formado por verbos que han cambiado o están cambiando su régimen, esto es, que se construían habitualmente en el español medieval con pronombres de dativo, como en latín, y que hoy están pasando a construirse mayoritariamente con pronombres de acusativo, como es el caso de **ayudar u obedecer**. Este proceso de cambio no se ha dado de manera uniforme en todas las áreas. Así, en las zonas no leístas del norte de España el régimen habitual es el dativo: «Vidal le ayudó. Y entre los dos lograron acercarlo al desmonte» (Aparicio Retratos [Esp. 1989]); en América está prácticamente generalizado el acusativo, sobre todo en los países del Cono Sur: «Natí lo ayudó a subir» (RBastos Hijo [Par. 1960]); Andalucía y Canarias son zonas de vacilación: «Lo ayudó a subir» (CBonald Noche [Esp. 1981]); «Ella le ayudó a recostarse en un sofá» (MñzMolina Invierno [Esp. 1987]).

Comment: Creo que el más común es: ¿Le ayudo?

Comment: He modificado la respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que se utiliza *le* para generalizar ya que *lo* es masculino y *la* es femenino, al usar *le*, no solamente le hablan de usted (cortesía), también generaliza para no encerrar a un género específico ya que muchas veces no saben si hablan con una mujer o un hombre.